# allowing multiple user inputs in java

Tags: java, input

I am making an A.I that carries on a conversation with you. 
when you run the program, the computer says hi,  and the user can enter multiple greetings back (like you, howdy etc.)

my question is when the computer asks the user "How are you?" and the user answers.  I programmed a switch where if you say something like "good" the computer will reply "Glad to hear it." , but it doesn't. what did I Do wrong?

here is my code:

```
    System.out.println("hi");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    System.out.println("The computer would like to remind you to reply with only a greeting");

    Scanner rexy = new Scanner(System.in);
    String domino = rexy.nextLine();


    switch (domino){
        case "hello":
            System.out.println("How are you?");
            break;

        case "hi":
            System.out.println("How are you?");
            break;

        case "howdy":
            System.out.println("How are you?");
            break;

        case "heyo":
            System.out.println("How are you?");
            break;

        case "hello?":
            System.out.println("How are you?");
            break;

        case "hey":
            System.out.println("How are you?");
            break;

        case "sup":
            System.out.println("How are you?");
            break;

        case "good":
            System.out.println("Glad to hear it");
            break;

        case "great":
            System.out.println("Glad to hear it");
            break;

        case "awesome":
            System.out.println("Glad to hear it");
            break;

        case "splendid":
            System.out.println("Glad to hear it");
            break;

        case "fantastic":
            System.out.println("Glad to hear it");
            break;


        case "fine":
            System.out.println("Glad to hear it");
            break;

        case "what's crackalakin?":
            System.out.println("How are you?");
            break;

        case "what's up turd face?":
            System.out.println("That's rude! How are you?");
            break;

    }
}
```

}

thanks.

Comment: @TNT, it works since `java 7`. Good morning :)

Comment: What errors do you get? Why doesn't it work? Does it gives a compilation error, runtime error, or simply prints nothing?

Comment: When something in code isn't working, please specify HOW it isn't working. Is it giving the wrong result? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but you should read about how switch statements default to *fall through*.  You really don't need the same `println()` statement over and over.

Comment: unprintable characters at the beginning or end of line.   readLine says it eats the <CR/LF>.  Something else perhaps?

Comment: Although not really related to your question, I'd suggest using `rexy.nextLine().toLowerCase()` or `switch(domino.toLowerCase())` so that the `domino` String can match up with any of the `case` statements regardless of case.

Comment: it just wasn't printing anything.

Comment: Put `System.out.println(domino)` before `switch (domino){` to see if the input is read correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a `default` statement to the switch, so that there is fallback for when the answer is not recognized; like that:

```
switch (domino) {
  //...
default:
    System.out.println("Sorry, I don't understand that.");
    break;
}
```

Furthermore, you can try printing the `domino` String, to see what is actually being read.

```
System.out.println(domino);
```

Also, a tip: you can join multiple equal `case` statements in a `switch` like so:

```
switch (domino) {
    case "hello":
    case "hi":
    case "howdy":
    case "heyo":
    case "hello?":
    case "hey":
    case "sup":
        System.out.println("How are you?");
        break;
    case "good":
    case "great":
    case "awesome":
    case "splendid":
    case "fantastic":
    case "fine":
        System.out.println("Glad to hear it");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really would like to do this simple but not really elegant - you can put the readLine and app answers in some kind of loop like below:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("hi");
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        System.out.println("The computer would like to remind you to reply with only a greeting");

        Scanner rexy = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean saidBye = false;

        while (saidBye == false) {
            String domino = rexy.nextLine();
            switch (domino) {
                case "hello":
                case "hi":
                case "howdy":
                case "heyo":
                case "hello?":
                case "hey":
                case "sup":
                case "what's crackalakin?":
                    System.out.println("How are you?");
                    break;
                case "good":
                case "great":
                case "awesome":
                case "splendid":
                case "fantastic":
                case "fine":
                    System.out.println("Glad to hear it");
                    break;
                case "what's up turd face?":
                    System.out.println("That's rude! How are you?");
                    break;
                case "bye":
                    System.out.println("Bye bye");
                    saidBye = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More elegant way would be to put every part of the conversation into separate method like that:

```
public class Android {

    private Scanner rexy;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

        Scanner rexy = new Scanner(System.in);
        Android android = new Android(rexy);
        android.greet();
        android.beNice();
        android.sayBye();
    }

    public Android(final Scanner rexy) {
        this.rexy = rexy;
    }

    public void greet() {

        System.out.println("hi");

        System.out.println("The computer would like to remind you to reply with only a greeting");

        String domino = rexy.nextLine();
        switch (domino) {
            case "hello":
            case "hi":
            case "howdy":
            case "heyo":
            case "hello?":
            case "hey":
            case "sup":
            case "what's crackalakin?":
                break;
            default:
                System.out.print("That's rude! ");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void beNice() {
        System.out.println("How are you?");
        String domino = rexy.nextLine();

        switch (domino) {
            case "good":
            case "great":
            case "awesome":
            case "splendid":
            case "fantastic":
            case "fine":
                System.out.println("Glad to hear it");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void sayBye() {
        System.out.println("OK. I have to go now.");
        String domino = rexy.nextLine();

        switch (domino) {
            case "bye":
            case "cu":
            case "see you":
                System.out.println("Bye");
                break;
        }
    } 
}
```

But it still has a lot of room for improvement ;)